# res.json returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, json, flutter

I try to login in my mobile app, here's the back-end code :

```
        // Track logins
        log(req, user.id, 'login', 'User successfully logged in.');

        // Everything is ok, return the data
        const returnObj = authenticateUserObject(user);
        returnObj.message = 'User successfully logged in.';
```

just before the res.json call everything is clear, but when I print the value of the user in the mobile app here's what I get :

```
I/flutter (10616): user{id: 12, roleId: 4, venueId: 1, email: test@gmail.com, password: null, firstName: test, lastName: test, birthDate: 2021-02-26T23:00:00.000Z, gender: m, phone: 0483334805, picture: , allergens: [], dietaries: [], participations: []}
```

all my arrays are empty do you know why ?

Comment: If the other fields are correct, chances are quite high, the data is not present in the answer, so it's probably missing on the server too.

Comment: no the data is not missing on the server

Comment: 0:{id: 1, venueId: 1, name: 'crown 2021 Event', startTime: Sun Jun 20 2021 22:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00), endTime: Sun Jun 20 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00), …}
1:{id: 2, venueId: 1, name: 'Stepinsight National Sales Conference', startTime: Thu May 20 2021 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00), endTime: Thu May 20 2021 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00), …}


here's for example the value of the participations array

Comment: Then you are doing something with it on the client side. If you put the data in on the server side it most certainly will pop out on the client side. Arrays don't empty themselves during transfer. Have you tried inspecting the requests in the devtools?

Comment: And on the server side you could also attach a debugger and check the object right before you really send it down to the client.

Comment: i've checked the object juste before it's sent to the client and it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Then you have to check the response on the client side, as early as possible, or even better in devtools